# Get last date PHP

Tags: php, date

I want to know how to get LAST DAY when I just know month and year. The month is integer and year is integer too. This is the codes :

```
<?php
$month = 2;
$year = 15; //I don't know why after "date('y',strtotime($tanggal_awal))" I get 15 not 2015

//how to know last date ????
?>
```

The real source is not like this. It's very long. I want to know PROPER MANNER TO GET last day WHERE MONTH IS FEBRUARY AND YEAR IS 2015.

Comment: not, I just make simple. the codes at above is enough

Comment: Last date? You mean the last day?

Comment: Just get the days in the month, that's the same as the 'last day' : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php

Comment: echo date("t", strtotime("..."));

Comment: @putvande yeah, you're right

Comment: @FDL You're right, you must answer

Comment: @Alex I have read the top answer. But, I don't read much. I don't find answer. But, when I read again second ago, I get what I want. Sorry !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`cal_days_in_month()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) function, the total number of days is the same as what the last day will be.

You may need to install the calendar functions in PHP, follow instructions here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php

As suggested in the comments you can also use [`date('t')`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), which doesn't require the above extension to be installed.

Comment: +1 for the right answer.

Comment: ```date('t')``` ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)) works withouth additional extensions

Comment: @user1781026 thanks I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the number of days of the desired month...

```
    int cal_days_in_month ( int $calendar , int $month , int $year )
```

Which gives the last date of the month.

[cal_days_in_month](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

Comment: I think newbie must read reference. Because he will confuse to fill $calendar

Comment: Here is the reference.